# html code for single-line line break

Tags: html

i would like to show this text in my html code:

```
<html>
Name 1 
Name 2
Managers
</html>
```

I tried to do this but then in the site it shows like this:

Name 1 Name 2 Managers.

If I put `<p>` on it, it will show like this:

```
<html>
<p>Name 1 </p>
<p> Name 2 </p>
<p> Managers </p>
```

The result is this:

Name 1

Name 2

Managers

Is there any code how to keep this single like?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [`<br>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) tag.

Note that you can change the spacing provided by a `<p>` tag by using [`CSS`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) properties like `margin`, `padding`, `line-height`, etc.

Comment: +1 for suggesting re-styling `<p>` tags as well as the obvious option of using `<br>` instead.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the `<br/>`, as others have pointed out, you can also enclose text content in the `<pre></pre>` tag, which will preserve all the whitespace.

Comment: `+1` didn't even think of that one.

Answer (score 5):

Use a line break `<br>`

```
<html>
Name 1<br>
Name 2<br>
Managers
</html>
```

From [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_br.asp):

> In HTML the `<br>` tag has no end tag.
>   In XHTML the `<br>` tag must be properly
>   closed, like this: `<br />`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<html>
Name 1<br />
Name 2<br />
Managers<br />
</html>
```